# ServiceStack, Root Path, Swagger API and Handler not Found

Tags: servicestack, swagger

All,

I have looked at all the issues in SO concerning Swagger support in ServiceStack when using root, but I am still coming up with a Handler for Request not found error for localhost:63219/swagger-ui/index.html

- VS2010
- Empty Web Project (Not MVC)
- ASP.NET 4
- ServiceStack 3.9.55

All my files involved in this issue are located here: https://gist.github.com/bp4151/c7544218b15b7d770f80

I am sure I am missing something. If anyone can help me out I'd appreciate it...

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid mistake. We were using

public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase

which is for console apps instead of

public class AppHost : AppHostBase

which is for IIS specifically. Once we made the switch, all our plugins started to work...